# Is the top row (menu, etc) customisable or is it fixed?

Tags: interface

Below is the screenshot of my top row (I don't know the correct term). Since it is long, I wrapped it in multiple rows, but they are actually one row.

There are I do not need, at least so far, like the "Scene", "View Layer", or the Blender icon button. And there is an empty area. But it is missing some button I would like to have. For example, I would like to have a button to "Toggle Window Fullscreen", or a button to minimise the window (when Blender is in Fullscreen, that button will be useful).

Can I add/remove things to/from the top row?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes it is!.**

Fortunately, there is a way to do that. :D

*Before*
[image]
*After*
[image]

The UI source code for the topbar is available in *`scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_topbar.py`*

As an example here I've quick and dirtily monkey patched a new draw method to the top bar.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.label(text="Taken OUT!")

bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.draw = draw
```

Note can undo this by calling scripts reload

```
bpy.ops.script.reload()
```

in the python console.

Most UI is alterable this way.  Enable [Developer Extras](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/preferences/interface.html#prefs-interface-dev-extras) to be able to right click on any property in layout and view source to see UI code.

For example the layout for Toggle window fullscreen button is

```
layout.operator("wm.window_fullscreen_toggle")
```